# Find a 4 digit number and get the text after them

Tags: sed, awk, grep, find, digit

i need to extract some numbers from a .sql file name:
from "TDB_full_335.51_2013_02_14.sql" i only want "2013_02_14"
i can get this with:

```
echo $(find -s ~/Downloads | grep -e '\.sql' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed -n '/TDB_full/p' | awk 'END{print}' | awk '{gsub(".sql", "");print}' | cut -d "_" -f4 -f5 -f6)
```

this is ok for now but if the filename length changes this will fail. is there a way to search for the 4 digits "2013" and get the digits after to ".sql"?

if found this:

```
grep -o '\([[:digit:]]\)\{4\}'
```

but gives me only "2013"

Comment: I don't think Ken Thompson had this in mind with the UNIX philosophy. That is one of the worst pipelines I've seen on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Find all `.sql` files in the `Downloads` folder for `2013` and print only the date:

```
$ find ~/Downloads -name "*.sql" | sed -r 's/.*(2013.*).sql/\1/'
2013_02_14
```

If you don't want to be restricted to the year `2013`:

```
$ find . -name "*.sql" | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}).sql/\1/'
2013_02_14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match 2013 and all following `0-9` and `_` easily;

```
grep -o '\(2013[0-9_]*\)'
```

Using `2013` hard coded may not be a good idea in the long run, so you may want to use something like;

```
grep -o '\(2[0-9]\{3\}_[0-9_]*\)'
```

...to match any 4 digit year starting with a 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` example:

```
find -name '*.sql' \
| sed 's/.*_\(\([0-9]*_\)\{2\}[0-9]*\)\.sql$/\1/'
```

Or if you are using the GNU version of `sed` you can pass the `-r` option. Then you won't need to escape the `{}` and `()`:

```
find -name '*.sql' \
| sed -r 's/.*_(([0-9]*_){2}[0-9]*)\.sql$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "TDB_full_335.51_2013_02_14.sql"  | awk '{print substr($0,match($0,/2013/),10)}'
2013_02_14
```